# \hspace is not working after \newline command

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I am currently working on my thesis report and would like to add affirmation to it. Following is the minimal code for the same :

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\section*{Affirmation}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Affirmation}
\hspace{1cm}something
\vspace{2cm}
\hspace{1cm}city, date \hspace{3cm}\line(1,0){200}
\newline
\hspace{8cm}(name)
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

It produces the following output[image: The output image]

As it can be seen, the (name) should come below the line, But due to some reason the `\hspace` before (name) isn't working.

Any help would in this regards would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that your picture wasn’t generated by this code?

Comment: No, It was generated by the code mentioned above.

Comment: Your code cannot produce this output because `\vspace` doesn’t do anything in the paragraph context you put it in. I pasted your code to writeLaTeX without changing anything, have a look: https://www.writelatex.com/151831vwvhtx. It seems to me that your screen shot was taken *before* you reduced your document to a MWE.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### What your code does

From the [unofficial LaTeX reference manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/latex2e), sec. 20.1:

> LaTeX normally removes horizontal space that comes at the beginning or
>   end of a line. To preserve this space, use the optional `*` form [of `\hspace`].

So let’s use `\hspace*` instead:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
    \section*{Affirmation}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Affirmation}
    \hspace{1cm}something
    \vspace{2cm}
    \hspace{1cm}city, date \hspace{3cm}\line(1,0){200}
    \newline
    \hspace*{8cm}(name)
    \clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

### What your picture says

The rest of the spacing is pretty different from your output because your screen shot was quite certainly not produced by the code you posted. With a bit of guesswork, I think this is closer to what you intended (note that you have to use the starred version of `\hspace` in several instances):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section*{Affirmation}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Affirmation}
\hspace*{1cm}something

\vspace{2cm}

\noindent\hspace*{1cm}city, date \hspace{3cm}\line(1,0){200}
\newline
\noindent\hspace*{8cm}(name)
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

### What I would suggest

Taking your layout and thinking about an implementation, I would do something like this, which is cleaner than meddling with a lot of spacing manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section*{Affirmation}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Affirmation}

something\\[2cm]
city, date \hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}\centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\\
    (name)
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you so much. That was really useful and it's working too :)

Comment: @Kishorepandey Glad it helps. I added some more details to my answer.

Comment: This answer just helped me with a similar problem of hspace at the start of a line. Thank you, kind stranger.

Answer (score 6):

As @doncherry said you can fix the problem using the starred version `\hspace*{}`. But I'm giving here an alternative solution to you to produce a line to sign. I usually use it.

```
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\begin{center}
\hrulefill\\
(date)
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
```

[image]