# \quad not working after using \newline

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I am just starting to use LaTeX and I like it a lot.

When I am in a `\subsection` or `\section` I can use `\quad` as much as I wish and it works properly until I use a `\newline` (or any line breaking command for that matter). Until I change to the next section, `\quad` will no longer work. Any reason why that is and how I can fix it?

An example:

```
\quad abc  \quad bbc \newline \quad test \newline
```

The output:

```
    abc    bbc
test
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! it because of the indent added with `\newline` try with `\newline \noindent`

Comment: `LaTeX normally removes horizontal space that comes at the beginning or end of a line` see [hspace-is-not-working-after-newline-command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109905/hspace-is-not-working-after-newline-command)

Comment: `\quad` is an `\hspace` (actually `\hskip`). If it were `\hspace*`, that would have worked.

Comment: @SAM: `\newline` doesn’t add `\indent` by itself, since it does not terminate the current paragraph, but forces a line break whitout leaving horizontal mode.  On the other hand,  if you do say `\newline\indent`, the space added by `\indent` will *not* disappear at line breaks (because it is actually a box).

Answer (score 21):

`TeX` removes spaces if they appear at the start of a line. You can insert a null object at the start of the line to prevent this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
aaa  \quad\quad\quad bbb \newline
ccc  \quad\quad\quad ddd \newline
\null\quad\quad\quad eee fff
\end{document}
```

[image: space]

Of course, manually inserting line breaks is unusual, but this is the explanation.

Comment: `\hspace*{1em}`, not `\null`

Comment: @IanThompson was wondering why adding manual line breaks is unusual. What would be a better approach?

Comment: @user3501476 --- It depends what you want to do. What are you using them for at the moment?

Comment: I was using the to create spacing after a table (embedded C++ code using the listings package). I also used them to create new paragraphs in a section which I suppose is incorrect.

Comment: @user3501476 --- Use a blank line in the code to indicate a new paragraph. There are better ways to insert space after a table, but I don't know what's best without seeing an example (you could ask a new question about this).

Comment: Note: If you use `\null` after a line that wasn't finished by `\newline` an empty line will be inserted. The solution with `\hspace` works in both cases. This is especially important if it is to be integrated into a command of which it is unknown where it will be called.

Answer (score 5):

`\quad` inserts an `\hskip` which is absorbed at the start of a new line. If you want it to be used, use `\hspace*{1em}` (which is similar to a `\quad`).

You can update `\quad` to take a `*` as a possible argument, thereby using `\hspace*` rather than `\hspace`. The latter is gobbled after a line-break:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\quad}{s}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\hspace*{1em}}
    {\hspace{1em}}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
aaa  \quad\quad\quad bbb \newline
ccc  \quad\quad\quad ddd \newline
\quad*\quad\quad eee fff

\end{document}
```

You could do the same for `\qquad`.