# Problems with spacing

Tags: spacing

I am quite new to LaTeX and I have a problem understanding how the spacing (like putting a tab with \quad) works in LaTeX. I just can't really get it to work:

```
\section{Top Section}
    \subsection{Subsection1}
        \subsubsection{Subsection2}
            \textbf{some bold print words} \\
            \quad THIS SPACING DOES NOT WORK
            \begin{itemize}
                \item item1
                \item item2
            \end{itemize}
            \quad THIS SPACING DOES WORK
```

yeah the problem I have is pretty much descirbed by the code above.
I just don't get why its working the second time but not the first time.

One further question as I already did creat this post anyway:
How could I "space" (like \quad) the whole itemization block?

Thanks alot for your help!

EDIT

I did end up using `\hspace*{Xmm}` instead of `\quad` where X is the distance in mm. That worked for me.
Nevertheless I am still wondering why the mentioned mehtod did not work like expected.

Comment: what is the output desired -- a handsketch perhaps?

Comment: Look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318454/quad-not-working-after-using-newline

Comment: Why don't you simply use a paragraph break instead of `\\\quad` and the `\quad` after the list?

Comment: You should almost never need a manual line break with `\\ ` or spacing such as `\quad`  just use structural commands like `\section` and  `\begin{itemize}` and ensure they have the layout that you need.  These commands are not defined by default in latex they are defined by the document class that you use, so as you have not provided and example it is hard to know what effect you are trying to achieve.

Comment: the answer to the added question is that `\quad` is `\hspace{1em}` but such space is dropped at start of line you need the `*` form `\hspace*` as you comment.  But you should not have such explicit spaces in a latex document in almost all cases.

Comment: Glue is discarded after a penalty.  Use `\null\quad`.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you are looking for a paragraph indent to mark the start of a paragraph. End of paragraph is marked by a blank line,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Top Section}
    \subsection{Subsection1}
        \subsubsection{Subsection2}
            \textbf{some bold print words}

            THIS SPACING DOES NOT WORK
            \begin{itemize}
                \item item1
                \item item2
            \end{itemize}

            THIS SPACING DOES WORK
\end{document}
```

You should avoid using `\\`  or explicit spaces in latex, the idea is that as far as possible you use structural markup and the layout and spacing is globally specified by the document class.

The specific issue why `\quad` did not work was that that is `\hspace{1em}` and such spaces are dropped after a linebreak (for the same reason that inter-word spaces are dropped at a linebreak). However if you do not use `\quad` at all, the issue goes away.